# Treat Text value as A Field

Tags: mysql, sql

In `MySql`, could we use text as a field?

```
SELECT (SELECT 'it_is_my_field_name_come_from_a_text') FROM my_table
```

Comment: However, `SELECT 'it_is_my_field_come_from_a_text'` is not a complete mysql query

Comment: @Wildan . . . Have you tested this?  It works fine.

Comment: That will work fine in MySQL (in some flavours of SQL you will need to use some kind of dummy table when doing your subselect, eg in Oracle it is called dual).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'it_is_my_field_come_from_a_text' FROM my_table ...
```

will work fine, maybe you could add the following alias to it:

```
AS `My Field From Text`
```

So, the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT 'it_is_my_field_come_from_a_text' AS `My Field From Text` FROM my_table ...
```